# Ruby #{} usage error

Tags: ruby

While I am new to Ruby, I have written a number of plugins for Ruby through trial and error.

I tried a number of different syntax variations which result in:

1. `Unexpected else or end, expecting }`
2. The variable not getting evaluated properly, i.e. `@reUrl` will end up = `"@reUrl2"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
def initialize(config)  
  self.reip1 = config["reip1"]  
  self.reip2 = config["reip2"]  
  @reUrl1 = "#{self.reip1}:8080/redeye/rooms/0/devices/2/commands/send?commandId="  
  @reUrl2 = "#{self.reip2}:8080/redeye/rooms/0/devices/2/commands/send?commandId="  
  @reUrl = @reUrl2  
end  

. 
. 
. 
. 


def change_redeye(redeye)  
  redeye = "#{redeye}".downcase  
  redeye = "#{redeye}".strip  
  redeyeid = "#{@redeyeId["#{redeye}"]}".to_i  
  if redeyeid > 0  
    say "OK. Changing to RedEye #{redeye}."  
    # results in resel = "@reUrl2"  Does what I want.      
    resel = "@reUrl#{redeyeid}"    
    # FIXIT: need to end up with the URL of the device, but can't find the right syntax.     
    @reUrl = "#{#{resel}}"           
  else    
    say "Sorry, I am not programmed to control RedEye #{redeye}."     
  end    
  request_completed     
end
```

Comment: The more I read your code, the more I realize it's unsalvageable. What is it you think that `#{}` is actually for? You're not using it correctly *anywhere*.

Comment: I have to agree--I really think you should take a step back for a moment or two and get a better handle on your environment.

Comment: *"I have written a number of plugins for Ruby through trial and error."* **There's your problem**. Wrapping everything in `#{}` "just in case" is no substitute for understanding what you're doing and writing *correct code*. It will eventually leave you with a mountain of unfixable code which is simply *one large bug* that needs rewriting.

Comment: "which is simply one large bug that needs rewriting." OMG, that was chilling, because, with my luck, my boss would ask me to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr I finally figured out what you're trying to do. While the below answer is still completely accurate in regards to your misuse of string interploation, what you're *actually* after is [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). I was failing to grasp that you were trying to access the value of a variable whose name was stored in a string.

---

There is a *lot* wrong here with your use of strings and interpolation. You only need to use `"#{}"` when you want to embed a variable inside a string. You're using it incorrectly in virtually every case. A few specific examples below.

First, don't do this:

```
redeye = "#{redeye}".downcase
redeye = "#{redeye}".strip
```

For one, you're converting to a string twice. It's already a string after the first use of `#{}`. But you shouldn't be doing that in the first place. If you want to convert a variable to a string, use `to_s`, and chain your subsequent method calls on the return value of the previous method:

```
redeye = redeye.to_s.downcase.strip
```

This line is *really* broken, and (as far as I can tell) doesn't even *need* string interpolation:

```
redeyeid = "#{@redeyeId["#{redeye}"]}".to_i
```

If `@redeyeId` is an array of integers, you just need this:

```
redeyeId = @redeyeId[redeye]
```

<strike>This line might be syntactically correctly but it's also pretty broken:</strike> This line is correct, if your intent is to use `instance_variable_get` to access the value of `@reUrl1` or `@reUrl2`:

```
"@reUrl#{redeyeid}"
```

You need to use `#{}` to interpolate `@variable` member variables as well as regular variables. The line should probably be

```
"#{@reUrl}#{redeyeid}"
```

This line is also *really* broken:

```
@reUrl = "#{#{resel}}"
```

What is this even supposed to do? I can't for the life of me figure out what your intent is here. What you're *actually* doing is, inside a string, opening a Ruby context which immediately opens a *comment*, resulting in the rest of the line being ignored and a syntax error on the following line. I can't tell what you think this does, but it doesn't do anything useful.

Because there is *so much wrong* here, I'm going to try to write the method as it *should* be written, and hope you can gain something from it. Before you write any more Ruby, you *need* to [learn what `#{}` does](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/). It is **string interpolation**.

```
def change_redeye(redeye)
  redeyeid = @redeyeId[redeye.downcase.strip]

  if redeyeid > 0
    say "OK. Changing to RedEye #{redeye}."
    @reUrl = instance_variable_get("@reUrl#{redeyeid}")
  else
    say "Sorry, I am not programmed to control RedEye #{redeye}."
  end
  request_completed   
end
```

Comment: I am using the #{variable} to convert the text to the value of the variable.  redeye is already a string.  i am stripping off blank spaces and changing the case

Comment: That is wrong. That's not what `#{variable}` does.

Comment: again I am new to ruby, but my code works so far.  just not the one line of code.   https://github.com/elvisimprsntr/siriproxy-redeye/blob/master/lib/siriproxy-redeye.rb

Comment: Your code works due to 100% luck, and it doesn't work the way you think it works. You are stumbling around in the dark, doing more harm than good.

Comment: Ahh, I finally grasp what you're trying to do. You're attempting to dynamically access a variable whose name is stored in a string. You want [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). Please see my edit. Note that this is a pretty atypical way of writing software. You'd generally store the values in an array, and compute the index in the array for the value you're after.

Comment: thanks again. now back to football.

Comment: I had to add a to_i to protect against the nil case.  redeyeid = @redeyeId[redeye.downcase.strip].to_i

Comment: Calling `nil.to_i` is a bad thing. That's not protecting yourself, that's introducing a subtle error. It *should* be producing a warning.

Comment: the hash lookup will result in a nil if it does not find a match.  the resulting "> 0 " check result in a crash.  my options are to initialize the hash to "0" or add the to_i check which seems to result in the nil converting to value of 0 which will satisfy the " > 0" check.  i am sure there is a lot i have to learn.  but as you said, "I am hacking around in the dark"  I'll be the first to admit that.  this was the error:

Comment: You *should* be checking whether the value exists in the array.

Comment: i thought that was the beauty of the hash key/value pairs.  if it does't find a match it returns what ever the hash is initialized to, which the default is nil.

Comment: It's still better to check for the existence of a key. Even if you don't want to, *leave it as nil* and use `unless redeyeid.nil?`

Comment: I have much to learn.    Thanks again.